# Не прикрепляет файл к письму

Tags: php, sendmail

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не прикрепляет файл на почту, а сама форма отрабатывает. При отправке данных с прикрепленным файлом, приходит письмо, но файл не прикрепляется(. Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией.
P.S. код не я писал

Сама форма

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="sendscript.php" method="POST" class="asyncformcall text-left form-order">    
    <input name='name' placeholder="Ваше имя" autocomplete="name" required class='txt' type="text" maxlength="80">
    <input type="phone" name='phone' placeholder="Ваш телефон" autocomplete="tel" required class='txt' maxlength="20" pattern="[+_0-9-\(\) ]{3,20}" title="Только цифры, -, пробелы, (), +">
    <div class="delim">
         <span>не обязательные поля</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $item ?>" name="item">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
    <input type="email" name='email' placeholder="Ваш e-mail" autocomplete="email" class='txt' maxlength="250" >
    <input name='address' placeholder="Адрес Вашего помещения" autocomplete="street-address" class='txt' type="text" maxlength="850">
    <input name='boss-name' placeholder="Ф.И.О Руководителя" autocomplete="off" class='txt' type="text" maxlength="150">
    <span style='padding-top: 10px;display: inline-block;height: 30px;'> Количество планов</span> <select name='plans-count' class="txt select-count">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5 и более">5 и более</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" class="item-form" value="call-order" name="item">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <span>Планировка Вашего помещения</span><br/>
    <div class="fileUpload btn-file">
        <span>Выбрать файл</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn2" name='plan-attachment' type="file" class="upload" />
    </div>
    <span id="uploadFile2">Файл не выбран</span>
    <center>
        <div id="recaptcha2"></div>
        <input class="order-submit" type="submit" value="Заказать план">
    </center>
 </form>
```

Сам обработчик

```
 <?php
      require_once 'recaptchalib.php';
      // Введите свой секретный ключ
      $secret = "тут ключ";
      // пустой ответ каптчи
      $response = null;
      // Проверка вашего секретного ключа
      $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
      if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
      $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
           $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
           $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
           );
      };
 $settings = array(
      'maxFileSize' => 10 * 1024, // 10 mb
      'sendTo' => 'asdasd@gmail.com'
 );

 if (isset($_FILES['plan-attachment'])) {
    /* --- simple script ---- */
      $fileName = basename($_FILES['plan-attachment']['name']);
      $fileSize = $_FILES["plan-attachment"]["size"] / 1024; //size in KBs
      if ($fileSize > $settings['maxFileSize']) {
        $errors = "Размер вложения не может быть более {$settings['maxFileSize']} кб";
        return $errors;
    }
    $tmp_path = $_FILES["plan-attachment"]["tmp_name"];
 }
function url() {
      return sprintf("%s://%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
      );
 }

 function mhe($str) {
      $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
      return '=?' . 'UTF-8' . '?B?' . base64_encode($str) . '?=';
 }
 if ($response != null && $response->success) { 
// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: 2color.ru <plam@2color.ru>" . $eol;
$headers .= "Reply-To: plam@2color.ru" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $random_hash . "\"" . $eol;

$body = '';
$date = date('H:i:s d.m.Y');
    $subject = "[ {$site} ] Новый заказ";
    $body = "Поступил новый заказ . Данные клиента:<br><hr>";
    $body.="Имя: {$_REQUEST['name']} <br>";
    $body.="Телефон: {$_REQUEST['phone']} <br>";
    $body.="<hr>";
    $body.=(isset($_REQUEST['email'])) ? "E-mail: {$_REQUEST['email']}<br>" : '';
    $body.=(isset($_REQUEST['address'])) ? "Адрес помещения : {$_REQUEST['address']}<br>" : '';
    $body.=(isset($_REQUEST['boss-name'])) ? "ФИО руководителя : {$_REQUEST['boss-name']}<br>" : '';
    $body.=(isset($_REQUEST['plans-count'])) ? "Кол-во планов : {$_REQUEST['plans-count']}<br>" : '';
    $body.=(isset($_REQUEST['item'])) ? "{$_REQUEST['item']}<br>" : '';
    $body.= "<br>Дата оформления заказа по времени сервера: " . $date;



//$body.="\n".$date;
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";

$nmessage = '';


$nmessage = "--" . $random_hash . $eol;
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
$nmessage .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

$nmessage = "--" . $random_hash . $eol;
$nmessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;" . $eol;
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
//$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $eol;
$nmessage .= $body . $eol;

if(!$_FILES["plan-attachment"]["name"])  
    {  
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["plan-attachment"]["name"];  
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["plan-attachment"]["tmp_name"])));  
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
    }

$nmessage .= "--" . $random_hash . '--';

$result = mail($settings['sendTo'], $subject, $nmessage, $headers);
 if ($result) {
      echo 'Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!';
      } else {
           echo 'Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!';
      }
 }
 else {
     echo 'Не пройдена каптча! Попробуйте еще раз!';
 }
```

Comment: Возможно дубликат: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826265/simple-php-form-attachment-to-email-code-golf?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Как отправить письмо c вложением (attachment) ? http://www.phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail